# Fruit bag swapping problem: fast python algorithm to swap packed items between two lists without changing item counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, random

I have a coding problem that is very hard to explain, so I came up with this fruit bag swapping problem that is very easy to understand:

A smart fruiterer sells 3 kinds of fruits: apples (denoted as `'A'`), bananas (denoted as `'B'`) and coconuts (denoted as `'C'`). The weird thing about him is that he always prepares 10 bags (bag id 0 to 9), including 3 small bags that can contain 2 fruits, 3 medium bags that can contain 4 fruits, 3 large bags that can contain 8 fruits, and one extra large bag that can contain 16 fruits. He only puts in same type of fruit into each bag. This can be abstracted to the following python code:

```
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase

#length = 30
#max_size = 10
#bag_sizes = [random.randint(1, max_size) for _ in range(length)]

n_fruit = 3
bag_sizes = [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 16]

random.seed(55)
fruiterer_bags = [[random.choice(ascii_uppercase[:n_fruit])] * bag_sizes[i] 
                  for i in range(len(bag_sizes))]
print(fruiterer_bags)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'A'], ['A', 'A'], ['A', 'A'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
 ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']]
```

Note that every day the fruiterer put fruits in each bag like this.

The supplier comes to the fruit shop every day with the same 10 bags, including 3 small, 3 medium, 3 large, 1 extra large. The bags are also assigned with id 0 to 9. He also only puts in same type of fruit in each bag, but the fruits he puts in each bag are not exactly the same as the fruiterer's. Every day he comes with the following bags:

```
random.seed(100)
supplier_bags = [[random.choice(ascii_uppercase[:n_fruit])] * bag_sizes[i] 
                 for i in range(len(bag_sizes))]
print(supplier_bags)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'], ['B', 'B'], 
 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
 ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```

The smart thing about this fruiterer is that every time the supplier comes, he wants to swap some fruit bags because they are fresher. The supplier says "OK, fine. You can swap however you like, you can do as many swaps as you want, but:

1. I don't swap the bags with the same type of fruits in them;
2. I must have the same amount of each fruit after all the swaps;
3. I only swap whole bags, not individual fruit;
4. I only swap bags with same ids;
5. Each bag can only be swapped once;
6. PLEASE BE FAST!"

Since `supplier_bags` has to have the same amount of each fruit after the swaps, then `fruiterer_bags` will of course also have the same amount of each fruit after the swaps. In this way, both fruiterer and supplier do not change the amount of each fruit on paper, but the smart fruiterer always gets fresher fruits. Every day the fruiterer and supplier come with same bags of fruits, but hopefully they can find very different ways of swapping bags (radomness).

My question is: is there any algorithm to get one possible solution very fast. The expected output is the **indices of the bags being swapped**. For example, one solution could be

```
swap_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and the `supplier_bags` after the swaps becomes:

```
new_supplier_bags = supplier_bags.copy()
for i in swap_ids:
    new_supplier_bags[i] = fruiterer_bags[i]
print(new_supplier_bags)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'A'], ['A', 'A'], ['A', 'A'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
 ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```

which still has the same amount of each fruit as before swaps. This can be checked by

```
assert sorted([f for bag in new_supplier_bags for f in bag]) == sorted(
              [f for bag in supplier_bags for f in bag])
```

Although I don't care about `fruiterer_bags`at all, it must also have the same amount of each fruit after the swaps.

I don't want all possible solutions. I just want one fast solution **with randomness**, because in reality I am dealing with lists of more than 200 "bag"s with various sizes and many types of "fruit"s, which is infeasible for an enumeration. I want an algorithm to work for any given `n_fruit`, `bag_sizes`, `fruiterer_bags` and `supplier_bags`. I guess a greedy algorithm will do.

Also, Is there any way to quick check if there is a solution at all? If not, maybe we can say there is no solution after the greedy algorithm suggests e.g. 1000 wrong solutions (if fast enough).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your definition of `he wants to swap some bags`? Like swap elements between `supplier_bags [i][j]` and `supplier_bags [l][m]`? And there should be random swaps of this kind - but why should there be the possibility that there is no solution?

Comment: No. I mean swap **whole bags**. The fruits cannot be taken out of the bags!

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. For the size 2 bags, can I just shuffle `idx = [0,1,2]` and then return `supplier_bags[*idx_shuffeld]`? Where we only allow versions of `idx_shuffeld` which are possible with 1 permutation and where the permuted bags have different content.

Comment: @user_na I don't quite understand your question, but I want to make this clear: every bag is distinguishable, i.e., they are labeled with id 0 to 9, so even though bag 0, 1, 2 are all size 2 bags, they are not same bags.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the link between the `fruiter_bags` and the `supplier_bags`. Are swaps in the `supplier_bags` replicated on at the `fruiter_bags`? Are they maybe between supplier and fruiter bag?

Comment: I don't care about ``fruiter_bags`` at all. Maybe the word "swap" is misleading. In fact, one can just leave ``fruiter_bags`` out there. The only thing I care is ``supplier_bags`` has to have same amount of each fruit, and that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233715/discussion-between-user-na-and-shaun-han).

Comment: Is the number of bags really as small as 10?  It seems that a pretty direct (randomized) backtracking search would work well here, but those are exponential time in the worst case.

Comment: No in reality I have 200 bags. I want an algorithm to work for any given ``bag_sizes`` (various number of bags, various sizes of bags). I understand it will be impossible to enumerate all solutions when the number of bags is large. I am just looking for one fast random solution.

Comment: Hi. I don't quite understand how these two requirements are compatible: *"I don't swap the bags with the same type of fruits in them"* with *"In this way, both fruiterer and supplier do not change anything on paper"*. Could you have meant *"I **only** swap the bags with the same type of fruits in them"*?

Comment: @AnnZen I meant they do not change the count of each fruit on paper, the bags, of course, can have different type of fruit after swaps, but the total counts of each type are the same.

Comment: @ShaunHan Oh, okay. I'll post an answer later.

Comment: @He3lixxx I know the complexity of this problem is too high. There is no possible way to get all solutions for my case (more than 200 bags). That's why I am asking for a greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase

def swaps(bags1, bags2):
    fruits = sorted([i for j in bags1 for i in j])
    zipped = list(map(list, zip(bags1, bags2)))
    idxs = [i for i, (bags1, bags2) in enumerate(zipped) if bags1 != bags2]
    while True:
        random.shuffle(idxs)
        for n, i in enumerate(idxs):
            zipped[i].reverse()
            if fruits == sorted(fruit for bags1, _ in zipped for fruit in bags1):
                return idxs[:n + 1]
        zipped = list(map(list, zip(bags1, bags2)))

n_fruit = 3
bag_sizes = [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 16]

random.seed(55)
fruiterer_bags = [[random.choice(ascii_uppercase[:n_fruit])] * i for i in bag_sizes]
random.seed(100)
supplier_bags = [[random.choice(ascii_uppercase[:n_fruit])] * i for i in bag_sizes]
random.seed()

print(swaps(fruiterer_bags, supplier_bags))
```

Running the code generates a random solution. Here are the results for 10 runs:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 3]
[5, 4, 3]
[4, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[3, 2, 4, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[3, 5, 4]
[4, 3, 5]
[5, 4, 3]
```

What I did in the code:

1. Define a list from zipping the two nested lists of strings, and define a list of all the indices of both nested lists that don't equal to each others at the same index.
2. Shuffle the list of indices and loop through the indice, reversing the element of the zipped list at the index of each iteration.
3. At any point in the looping, if all the strings sorted in the first element of each element in the zipped list equals to all the strings sorted in the original first nested list, we got a solution, can we can return it.

Comment: Thanks! The answer looks very clean and it works well for my case (more than 200 bags). The only problem is the code will run forever if there is no solution at all. For example, you can try ``bag_sizes = [1, 2, 5, 8]``, which obviously doesn't have a solution. I need a robust way to handle no-solution situations as well.

Comment: If the above solution is fast enough for you, cannot you simply add a `maxruns` parameter to `swaps` and substitute the `while` loop with a `for run in range(maxruns)` (with an `else` clause for handling the "no solutions found" case)?

Comment: @gimix Sure. I guess there's no other options.

Comment: @ShaunHan I had gimix's solution in mind. Also, it may improve efficiency even more to append the `idx` variable to a list after every `for` loop, so that we can do `if idx in idx_list: continue` after every shuffle :)

Comment: @AnnZen I cannot find ``idx`` in your code. Do you mean ``idxs``? I tried with ``idxs`` and it doens't work.

Comment: @ShaunHan Ah yes, I meant `idxs`. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGwjB.png). But on the other hand, it also slows things down because we need to create a copy of `idxs` every time we append it to the list.